# keydown EventListener in IE7

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-7

I've written this code inside the HEAD tags of my HTML page. It works fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but doesn't in IE7. I would like to know how to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    alert(e.keyCode);
  }, true);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has implemented their own way of doing this called `attachEvent`. You can read more about this over at quirksmode.org: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no `window.addEventListener` in IE, you need to use `attachEvent`. There's good documentation on events [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html), or you could switch to using a library that abstracts away browser differences.

Answer (score 2):

You're screwed: you're using [event capturing](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-capture) (passing `true` as the last parameter to `addEventListener`). IE has *no* such equivalent, in *any* version, including IE8 in IE8 mode.

Is there a reason you must use event capturing rather that event bubbling here? IOW, pass `false` as your last parameter? Then, you'd be able to port this (somewhat) to use IE's `attachEvent` proprietary method, or use a library (as others have suggested and added links for).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.attachEvent
```

More fully:

```
//set page event handlers
if (window.attachEvent) {
//IE and Opera
window.attachEvent("keydown", "");
} else if (window.addEventListener) {
// IE 6
window.addEventListener("keydown", "");
} else {
//FireFox
document.addEventListener("keydown", "");
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot the "on"-prefix for attachEvent, so "onkeydown" rather than "keydown"